# Play Store Console ad declaration page disabled

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I'm trying to roll out an app as an alpha on the Play Store, however, although the release page says the app is ready to be rolled out, the rollout button is disabled.

If you look at the screenshot, the checklist is not complete, I need to add the ads declaration. But when I try to do that, the "save" button is disabled.

Anybody who has experienced that and have a solution?

Thanks!

[image: Play Store Console showing Ads page with buttons disabled]

Answer (score 5):

Try disable Adblock Plugin and refresh the page.